# Display post author avatar for Ultimate Member

Tags: plugins, avatar

I want to show avatar from the post author. I use Ultimate Members and want to show the avatars that are defined via UM.

```
<?php
global $post;
$url = get_avatar_url( $post, array( 'size' => 48 ));
$img = '<img alt="" src="'. $url .'">';
echo $img;
?>
```

But this code shows the gravatars or default avatar. How can I get the avatars from Ultimate Member?

Answer (score 0):

To get user's avatars of the UM plugin, you have to do this :

```
// Returns a given user's avatar
um_get_user_avatar_url( $user_id = '', $size = '96' )
```

Comment: If i use your code, i get the default avatar URL:

`<img alt="" src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e?s=400&amp;r=G&amp;d=http://work.cultural-managers.net/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/assets/img/default_avatar.jpg">`

Comment: I tried these codes:
`$url = um_get_user_avatar_url( $user_id = '', $size = '96' );`
`$url = um_get_user_avatar_url( $user_id = '$my_post->post_author', $size = '96' );`
and get the default avatar URL.

Answer (score 0):

Moderator has delete this answer, but this code work:

```
get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), 48 );
```